# How do I unlock Yves?

Tags: cadence-of-hyrule

I have noticed through watching speedruns that there is an unlockable deku scrub character called Yves. I'd like to do a Yves run, the problem is I don't know how to unlock them. How do I unlock Yves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can unlock Yves by collecting a grand total of twenty Deku Seeds, which you can obtain from defeating Deku Scrubs during the game.

Deku Scrubs are the brown/green leafy fellas that hide underground and shoot seeds at you once you're in their line of sight:

[image: Deku Scrub Enemy]

Using a shield to deflect said seeds back at them will kill them - once you do so, a Deku Seed can be collected off of them:

[image: Deku Seed Drop]

Once you collect 20, you can turn them in at Tingle's cave in the Lost Woods area - the first 10 you turn in will net you a stamina upgrade, the next 10 will unlock Yves for play:

[image: Tingle and Yves Reward]

Comment: I'd like to add that there's a cave in the lost woods that contains many Deku Scrubs.

Comment: @Zeta Thank you so much for this additional info, I was wondering how I could be missing deku nuts if my map didn't have any